# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't change next/previous picture

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've been trying to make a portfolio website in Django, I've been following some tutorial for this.
The Carousel on my page doesn't seem to change images when clicking next/previous button. The images displays properly (need to resize it for appropriate looks) but no matter what I do it won't show next/previous image.
I am providing the carousel code and the whole html code:

**Carousel code:**

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?food,food" alt="First slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?cat,cat" alt="Second slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?car,car" alt="Third slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Whole HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"         
rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"     
crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OMEGA</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/project">Project</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- 
   label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?food,food" alt="First 
  slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?cat,cat" alt="Second 
 slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?car,car" alt="Third 
 slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

<!-- <h1>Hello, world!</h1> -->

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you see an error in console log?

Comment: @kabooya Nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to remove "active" from second and third img tags in your carousel code**

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?food,food" alt="First slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?cat,cat" alt="Second slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?car,car" alt="Third slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**To**

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?food,food" alt="First slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?cat,cat" alt="Second slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x800/?car,car" alt="Third slide" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **data-ride** and **data-slide** to **data-bs-ride** and **data-bs-slide**. In bootstrap 5  data-ride and data-slide don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

As your are using bootstrap 5, you must use `data-bs-ride="carousel"` and `data-bs-slide="carousel"` at the places of `data-ride="carousel` and `data-slide="carousel`. After that The `.active` class needs to be added to one of the slides otherwise the carousel will not be visible so remove it for the second and the third slide.

Link: [Bootstrap 5 carousel with indicators](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators)

**Solution 2**

Just change the version of your bootstrap to 4 and remenber to set `.active` class for only one slide.